# why is the warning sign popping out? in lisp programming

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, allegro, allegro-cl

Why is this "Warning: Free reference to undeclared variable ARAD assumed special." popping out?

```
(defstruct Place()
  (pathCost  10)
  (childName 'none)
)

(setf Arad(make-Place :childName 'Zerind))

(describe Arad)
```

Comment: You didn't declare the variable arad, you just assigned to it.  You need to declare a global variable with defparameter or defvar (e.g., **(defparameter \*arad* (make-place ...))**), or declare a local variable with let, e.g., **(let ((arad (make-place ...))) ...)**.

Comment: Turn your CamelCase into lisp-case.. And put spaces after symbols.